# Probability, understanding part from textbook(impossible)

Tags: probability

I am reading this probability book, and I just got stuck why the inequality only can hold if B is impossible. (marked in red) Could someone explain this, since I do not get what happens with the inequality if one element is impossible.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this way:

$A$ is more plausible given $B,C''$:
$$P(A|B,C'')>P(A|B,C)$$
$B$ does not change:
$$P(B|C'')=P(B|C)$$
Then as long as
$$P(A,B) = P(A|B)P(B)$$
[then](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927592/conditional-probability-conditioned-twice) it should be 
$$P(A,B|C'') = P(A|B,C'')P(B|C'')$$
Now we know that when $C\rightarrow C''$ the second probability $P(B|C'')$ doesn't change, while the first $P(A|B,C'')$ increases.
As long as this inequality is strict ($>$), the only option for equality is $P(B|C)=P(B|C'')=0$.